# Can community user create tasks?

Tags: community, permissions, profile

Can a community user create a task for a lead ? What profile permissions does he need to create ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the type of Community you have. See [Communities Users Licenses](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US) for features by license type. Only Partner Community Users can create Tasks. For the other license types, Tasks are read only.